# Render image dynamically from local assets

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm having trouble display local assets from the local assets folder. The structure should be as follow:

Asset folder:

```
/-----/assets/doctor-images 
      screen/DashboardScreen.tsx
```

Currently, I'm using a flatlist to display data from a array as follow:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
    speciality: "Cardiology",
    title: "Dr. Bellamy N",
    distance: "12 mins",
  },
  {
    id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
    speciality: "Cardiology",
    title: "Dr. Mensah T",
    distance: "30 mins",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
    speciality: "Cardiology",
    title: "Dr. Klimisch J",
    distance: "70 mins",
  },
  {
    id: "1448f961-3b5d-4d81-895e-aac96aefdbed",
    speciality: "Cardiology",
    title: "Dr. Klimisch J",
    distance: "70 mins",
  },
  {
    id: "3aa28493-2173-4082-bc6f-78a1d9d0c689",
    speciality: "Cardiology",
    title: "Dr. Klimisch J",
    distance: "70 mins",
  },
  {
    id: "20ce3cd5-55b4-424c-a46a-1555bf625dbc",
    speciality: "Cardiology",
    title: "Dr. Klimisch J",
    distance: "70 mins",
  },
];
```

My ideal is when the flatlist going though the list, it will have the id of the block it's trying to render. Then I will get that id and try to conditional render the Image component. Matching the id is the file-name.png. So far I got to this.

Item to display is flatlist:

```
const Item = ({title, speciality, distance, id}: ItemProps) => {
  let imageUrl = "";

  RNFS.readFile(`${id}.png`, "base64").then(res => {
    imageUrl = res;
  });

  console.log("imageUrl" + imageUrl);
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />;
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{speciality}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{distance}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Flatlist code:

```
<FlatList
  data={DATA}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  numColumns={2}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.itemContainer}
      id={index.toString()}
      onPress={() => console.log("pressed")}>
      <Item
        title={item.title}
        speciality={item.speciality}
        distance={item.distance}
        id={item.id}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

So far I cannot get the image display using path. I heard that a better way is to convert it in to base64 URI and put it in the `source`, but no luck getting that to happen so far.

I have tried `let [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState("");` to save the URI and then decode, but it just send me to infinite loop when I try

```
RNFS.readFile(`${id}.png`, "base64").then(res => {
  setImageUri(`data:image/png;base64,${res}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that you imageUrl should be created from the `useState` hook and then updated on component mount; which means using `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```js
const Item = ({title, speciality, distance, id}: ItemProps) => {
  const [imageUrl,setImageUrl] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    RNFS.readFile(`${id}.png`, "base64").then(res => {
      setImageUrl(res);
   });
  },[]);

  console.log("imageUrl" + imageUrl);
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />;
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{speciality}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{distance}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

RNFS uses the device's file system to read files; and I dont think it by default gives access to the asset folder in an app's source code; so I think even now it would fail. The good news is that since the files are in your app bundle, you can access them using require. I'd recommend creating a `imagesAssets.js` file where its keys are the file ids, and the values the image imports. Doing this will make it abstract your code more, and make it easier to preload the images with something like [useAssets](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/#useassetsmoduleids):

```js
export default {
  'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba': require('./bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba.png'),
  '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63': require('./3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63.png'),
  '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72': require('./58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72.png'),
  '1448f961-3b5d-4d81-895e-aac96aefdbed': require('./1448f961-3b5d-4d81-895e-aac96aefdbed.png'),
  '3aa28493-2173-4082-bc6f-78a1d9d0c689': require('./3aa28493-2173-4082-bc6f-78a1d9d0c689.png'),
  '20ce3cd5-55b4-424c-a46a-1555bf625dbc': require('./20ce3cd5-55b4-424c-a46a-1555bf625dbc.png'),
};
```

Now import imageAssets and use the id to get the proper image:

```js
const Item = ({title, speciality, distance, id}: ItemProps) => {
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image source={{uri: imageAssets[id]}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />;
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{speciality}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{distance}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then if you wanted to prefetch with `useAssets`:

```js
const [assets, assetsError] = useAssets(Object.values(imageAssets))
```